# I can't update password in mysql database with sha1 (php forgot password system)

Tags: php, mysql, database

First of all I'm very new to PHP so don't be to hard on me. I'm trying to make a forgot password system for my website, but I can't update the password in the mysql database with sha1. If I do it before sha1 encrypting it works(commented out query in the code)

What I want is to receive a random password on the users mail, but in the database I want it to be encrypted with sha1.

Could really use some help here.

```
<?php

include("connect.php");

    if(isset($_POST["email"])) {
        $email = $con->real_escape_string($_POST["email"]);

        $data = $con->query("SELECT * FROM bruker WHERE ePost='$email'");

        if ($data->num_rows > 0) {
            $str = "0123456789qwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnmQWERTYUIOPASDFGHJKLZXCVBNM";
            $str = str_shuffle($str);
            $str = substr($str, 0, 15);

            $passwordD = $str;

            //$con->query("UPDATE bruker SET passord = '$passwordD' WHERE ePost='$email'");

            echo $passwordD;

            $url = "http://localhost/example";

            $msg = "Your new password is: $passwordD\nTo change your password, please visit this: $url";
            $subject = "Reset Password";
            $headers = "From: Vikerfjell" . "\r\n";

            mail($email, $subject, $msg, $headers);

            $salt = 'IT2_2017';
            $passwordE = sha1($salt.$passwordD);

            echo $passwordE;

            $con->query("UPDATE bruker SET passord = '$passwordE' WHERE ePost='$email''");

        } else {
            echo "Please check your link:";
        }



    } else {
        header("Location: index.php");
    }

mysqli_close($con);

?>
```

Comment: You can directly use sha1(password) in mysql statement. `UPDATE bruker SET passord = sha1($passwordE) `

Comment: You are passing a different string to the `sha()` method that what you are sending to your users, therefore the `sha()` they make at login won't match what you've generated

Comment: **Danger**: You are using [an unsuitable hashing algorithm](http://php.net/manual/en/faq.passwords.php) and need to [take better care](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Password_Storage_Cheat_Sheet) of your users' passwords.

Comment: You may want to consider using prepared queries instead, since you are using mysqli anyway.  And you have a typo in your last query; `passord`.

Comment: Just using a hash function is not sufficient and just adding a salt does little to improve the security. Instead iIterate over an HMAC with a random salt for about a 100ms duration and save the salt with the hash. Use functions such as `PBKDF2`, `Rfc2898DeriveBytes`, `password_hash`, `Bcrypt` and similar functions. The point is to make the attacker spend a lot of time finding passwords by brute force.

Comment: If you are using PHP them the best secure choice is to use `password_hash` and `password_verify`, easy and secure, what more could one ask for.

Comment: Thanks pbu! It's working now.

Comment: I have to use sha1 with a specific salt according to the assignment. Any tips for doing it more secure are welcome, but I have to use sha1 with specific salt.

Answer (score 0):

```
  <form name="form" action="" method="post">
  <input type="text" name="email"  value="">
  <input type="submit" name="update password" />
  </form
```

check the form method in the first then remove the single qoute in this line of code to be as shwon

```
$con->query("UPDATE bruker SET passord = '$passwordE' WHERE ePost='$email' ");
```

Note: the mail function will not work on the localhost